# how to send form data in ajax with multiple files without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

in my form code there is text input, checkbox input, file input type...etc,
everything working fine except the file input it's only taking one value ( multiple files upload isn't sending through ajax call ) how can i send arrays inside the **serialize()** function ?

- Code :

  ```
    <form action="#" id="postAdd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" type="file" class="form-control-file d-none" id="file-upload" name="file[]" multiple required>
     <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control bg-white" name="discName[]">
     <button id="postAdbtn" class="btn btn-primary d-block mt-2">Submit</button>
    </form>     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postAdbtn').click(function() {
            var form = $('#postAdd').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'add-product-done.php',
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    form: form
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.fetchData').html(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
  ```

one more thing, how can i get the files in **PHP** ?
and thanks

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like this?

```
var form = new FormData($("postAdd"));    

$.ajax({
  url: 'add-product-done.php',
  data: form,
  contentType: "multipart/form-data",
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.error(err);
  }

});
```